# Modify jquery range pie chart to allow compensatory change only in next/previous label

Tags: jquery, pie-chart, adjustable

I want to modify this jquery pie chart so that, when any one label is modified, the change happens only in the next label. If the next label is 0, then the change should happen in previous label. It this too is 0, then no change should happen.

Right now what is happening is, if you make changes in any label; the compensatory change happens in all the labels. But this isn't helpful. Because users may want to fix one label then adjust other labels.

Please help.

```
    var nb_sliders = null; // nb of range sliders
var moving_id = null; // id of the moved slider
var oldValue = []; // previous values of the sliders

var radius = 150; // pie chart radius
var color = d3.scale.category20(); // color scheme (10, 20, 20b, 20c ...)
var pi = Math.PI; // 3.14

// pie chart config
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.value;
})
//.startAngle(-90 * (pi/180))
//.endAngle(90 * (pi/180))
.sort(null);

// arc object
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius / 2);

// nb sliders event
d3.select('#nbFormSubmit').on('click', function () {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    nb_sliders = d3.select('#nbSliders')[0][0].value;
    init();
});

// initialize the sliders, events and pie chart
function init() {
    oldValue = [];
    moving_id = null;

    d3.select('#rangebox tbody').html('');

    // append sliders to table
    for (i = 0; i < nb_sliders; i++) {
        var tr = d3.select('#rangebox tbody').append('tr');
        tr.append('td')
            .attr('class', 'edit')
            .attr('contenteditable', true)
            .text('Label ' + (i + 1));
        tr.append('td')
            .append('input')
            .attr('type', 'range')
            .attr('data-id', i)
            .attr('class', 'range')
            .attr('step', 1)
            .attr('min', 0)
            .attr('max', 100);
        tr.append('td')
            .attr('class', 'range_value');
    }

    d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {
        var def = parseInt(100 / nb_sliders);
        this.value = def;
        oldValue[d3.select(this).attr('data-id')] = this.value;
    });

    equalize();
    showValues();
    pieChart();

    // content edit event
    d3.selectAll('.edit').on('input', function () {
        updateLabels();
    });

    // slider event
    d3.selectAll('.range').on('change', function () {
        this.value = parseInt(this.value);
        if (this.value < 0) this.value = 0;
        else if (this.value > 100) this.value = 100;

        var id = d3.select(this).attr('data-id');
        moving_id = id;

        var old_value = oldValue[moving_id];
        var new_value = this.value;
        var delta = (new_value - old_value) / (nb_sliders - 1);

        d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {
            var r_id = d3.select(this).attr('data-id');
            var r_val = this.value;
            if (r_id != moving_id && r_val > delta) {
                var equalized = parseInt(r_val - delta);
                this.value = equalized;
                oldValue[r_id] = this.value;
            }
        });

        oldValue[moving_id] = new_value;

        equalize();
        showValues();
        updatePieChart();
    });
}

// get JSON data from sliders
function getData() {
    var json = [];
    d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {

        json.push({
            label: d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode)
                .select('td:first-child')
                .text(),
            value: this.value
        });
    });
    return json;
}

// compute total percentage from sliders
function getTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt(this.value);
    });
    return total;
}

// equalize the sliders (decimal delta)
function equalize() {
    var remaining = 100 - getTotal();

    if (remaining != 0) {
        var to_eq = null;
        var min = null;
        var max = null;
        var min_value = 9999;
        var max_value = 0;

        console.log(remaining);

        d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {
            var id = d3.select(this).attr('data-id');

            if (id != moving_id) {
                if (parseInt(this.value) > parseInt(max_value)) {
                    max_value = this.value;
                    max = this;
                }
                if (parseInt(this.value) < parseInt(min_value)) {
                    min_value = this.value;
                    min = this;
                }
            }
        });

        if (remaining > 0) to_eq = min;
        else to_eq = max;

        if (to_eq) {
            if (remaining > 0) {
                to_eq.value = parseInt(to_eq.value) + 1;
                remaining = remaining - 1;
            } else {
                to_eq.value = parseInt(to_eq.value) - 1;
                remaining = remaining + 1;
            }
            oldValue[d3.select(to_eq).attr('data-id')] = to_eq.value;

            if (remaining != 0) equalize();
        }
    }
}

// show slider value
function showValues() {
    d3.selectAll('#rangebox .range').each(function () {
        var perct = this.value + '%';
        d3.select(this.parentNode.nextSibling).html(perct);
    });
}

// draw pie chart
function pieChart() {
    var json = getData();

    d3.select("#pie svg").remove();

    // svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#pie")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", radius * 2)
        .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

    // slices
    var arcs = svg.selectAll("path").data(pie(getData()))

    // render the slices
    arcs.enter()
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .each(function (d) {
        this._current = d;
    })
        .append('title')
        .text(function (d, i) {
        return json[i].value + '%';
    });

    // render the labels
    arcs.enter()
        .append("svg:text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d, i) {
        if (json[i].value > 1) return json[i].label;
        else return null;
    });
}

// update pie chart
function updatePieChart() {
    updateArcs();
    updateLabels();
}

// update the slices of the pie chart
function updateArcs() {
    var json = getData();

    d3.selectAll("#pie path title")
        .text(function (d, i) {
        return json[i].value + '%';
    });

    d3.selectAll("#pie path")
        .data(pie(json))
        .transition()
        .duration(700)
        .attrTween('d', arcTween);
}

// update the labels of the pie chart
function updateLabels() {
    d3.selectAll("#pie text")
        .data(pie(getData()))
        .transition()
        .duration(700)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .text(function (d, i) {
        if (getData()[i].value > 0) return getData()[i].label;
        else return null;
    });
}

// transition for the arcs
function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function (t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of changing the labels with your unexpected result, and with what you indent to happen?